# What is this data type?

Tags: php, json

It's in a php project. But did not understand what type of data.

I want to parse it to json.

```
a:10:{i:1;s:2:"49";i:2;s:2:"53";i:3;s:3:"140";i:4;s:2:"53";i:5;s:2:"53";i:6;s:2:"40";i:7;s:2:"40";i:8;s:2:"60";i:9;s:2:"40";i:10;s:0:"";}
```

Comment: It is [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) data. You have to deserialize it and then You can made Yours json from it.

Answer (score 3):

***It's called*** `serialized data`

***1.*** You can [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it to convert it to array

```
<?php

$data = 'a:10:{i:1;s:2:"49";i:2;s:2:"53";i:3;s:3:"140";i:4;s:2:"53";i:5;s:2:"53";i:6;s:2:"40";i:7;s:2:"40";i:8;s:2:"60";i:9;s:2:"40";i:10;s:0:"";}';

$unserialized_array = unserialize($data);

print_r($unserialized_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/993433

***2.*** You can use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to pares it to json

```
<?php

$data = 'a:10:{i:1;s:2:"49";i:2;s:2:"53";i:3;s:3:"140";i:4;s:2:"53";i:5;s:2:"53";i:6;s:2:"40";i:7;s:2:"40";i:8;s:2:"60";i:9;s:2:"40";i:10;s:0:"";}';

$json_data = json_encode(unserialize($data));

echo $json_data;
```

Output:-https://eval.in/993437

Answer (score 1):

That is serialized data; you can use [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to get the contents;

```
$a = 'a:10:{i:1;s:2:"49";i:2;s:2:"53";i:3;s:3:"140";i:4;s:2:"53";i:5;s:2:"53";i:6;s:2:"40";i:7;s:2:"40";i:8;s:2:"60";i:9;s:2:"40";i:10;s:0:"";}';
print_r(unserialize($a));
```

returns:

```
   Array ( 
      [1] => 49 
      [2] => 53           
      [3] => 140 
      [4] => 53 
      [5] => 53 
      [6] => 40
      [7] => 40 
      [8] => 60 
      [9] => 40 
      [10] =>
 )
```

Then you can just run a `json_encode()` on your now serialized data to get the output you wanted...

```
 $a = 'a:10:{i:1;s:2:"49";i:2;s:2:"53";i:3;s:3:"140";i:4;s:2:"53";i:5;s:2:"53";i:6;s:2:"40";i:7;s:2:"40";i:8;s:2:"60";i:9;s:2:"40";i:10;s:0:"";}';

echo json_encode(unserialize($a));
```

returns:
`{"1":"49","2":"53","3":"140","4":"53","5":"53","6":"40","7":"40","8":"60","9":"40","10":""}`

Answer (score -1):

it's serialized data; You can unserialize it and convert to json;

```
<?php
$data = 'a:10:{i:1;s:2:"49";i:2;s:2:"53";i:3;s:3:"140";i:4;s:2:"53";i:5;s:2:"53";i:6;s:2:"40";i:7;s:2:"40";i:8;s:2:"60";i:9;s:2:"40";i:10;s:0:"";}';
echo json_encode(unserialize($data));
```

it's [example](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/bW), just press execute and you will get your json;

Comment: Link only answer are not liked on SO. The linked content tends to get removed, making the answer useless. Better to include at least the main information in the answer

Comment: sorry, did not see the question about json; updated my answer;

Comment: Again with Off Site Links

Comment: This is not just a link to the code, it can also be executed. As for me, this is a more visual solution.

Comment: But will it be there in the year 2020? Your answer might be!